# Is it advisable for software developers to focus on frameworks like React or Vue?

Tags: career-development, career-switch

As a front end developer just 2 years into my career, I am starting to be confused by the job industry nowadays where the job recruiters are looking for people who had experience with React or Angular for X amount of years.
I have read what people wrote online saying that do not focus too much on frameworks as they come and go, rather focus on picking up OOP languages like Java or Python.

For front end developers, this is a very difficult situation because if frameworks come and go, that means our ROI learning and working on those frameworks will be disappointing. So would that mean back end developers will have an edge in the industry because what they learn (database, backend OOP languages)would still be practical 10 years down the line?

Should I switch my job to become a backend developer then? Or rather instead of focusing on learning frameworks, I should just focus on learning a backend programming language then (either Python, Java, Golang)?
Really need advise as a newbie programmer here.

Comment: This is more of a career advice question than workplace problem, but I'll comment since I'm a front end developer. While it is a bit annoying that front end tech goes through these comparatively fast cycles, if you know the core stuff well (HTML,CSS and JS) then picking up new frameworks as they come is pretty easy. And front end devs are in high demand at the moment and likely will be for a while, with people doing everything in their lives online. It's ok to not use the same small stack for 30+ years. Do what most interests you. Besides, you can always do full stack work.

Comment: alright I have moved my topic there. Thanks guys

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily opinion based